# In CruiseControl.NET, when buildCondition="IfModificationExists" build is triggered by change on any branch, not changes to the configured branch

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I'm Using CruiseControl.NET with git. I've got two projects configured, each for a different branch in the same repository.  I've configured an intervalTrigger for buildCondition="IfModificationExists" for each project.  The problem is that the build is running for both projects whenever there is a change *on any branch in the repository*, instead of the only on the branch configured for the project.

More specifically, I have configured two CCNet projects, ProductionCI and ReleaseCandidateCI for the respective branches Production and ReleaseCandidate. When I merge changes to the branch ReleaseCandidate, the project ReleaseCandidateCI build as expected.  However, so does the project ProductCI, even though nothing changed on the Production branch.

This is mostly just an annoyance, because each project executes every time its required. They just also execute when it's not useful.

Here is my configuration:

**File trigger.xml**

```xml
<cb:config-template xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger
            name="continuous"
            seconds="600"
            buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
            initialSeconds="5"/>
        </triggers>
</cb:config-template>
```

**File ccnet.config**

```xml
<project>
   <name>ProductionCI</name>
    ...
    <cb:include href="trigger.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"/>
    ...
    <sourcecontrol  type="multi">
        <sourceControls>
            <git>
                <repository>[url to repo]</repository>
                    <branch>Production</branch>
                    <workingDirectory>[path to directory]</workingDirectory>
                    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
            </git>
        </sourceControls>
    </sourcecontrol>    
    ...
</project>
<project>
    <name>ReleaseCandidateCI</name>
    ...
    <cb:include href="trigger.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"/>
    ...
    <sourcecontrol  type="multi">
        <sourceControls>
            <git>
                <repository>[url to repo]</repository>
                <branch>ReleaseCandidate</branch>
                <workingDirectory>[path to directory]</workingDirectory>
                <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
            </git>
        </sourceControls>
    </sourcecontrol>    
    ...
</project>
```

Note: I am aware that using separate repositories instead of branches will solve this problem, but it's not really an option.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What if you combined the build job of your branches under one project, and replace the `<sourcecontrol type='multi'>` with two  `<sourcecontrol type='git'>` blocks?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Setting sourcecontrol type="git" causes the pull to fail.  I ran into that when I initially set the projects up.  According to the documentation it has to be set to "multi" http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Multi_Source_Control.  And combining the build projects will not do what I want, which is only build on the Production or ReleaseCandidate branch if they were changed.

Comment: What CC.NEt version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate why the `git` sourcecontrol block doesn't work.
With this standard block, it works for me.

Are you sure you are using the **path to the remote repository** ?  Do not use a local path from a checkout you prepare in previous step (I don't think you made it but I prefer to be clear here).

```xml
<sourcecontrol type="git">
  <repository>git://github.com/rails/rails.git</repository>
  <branch>ReleaseCandidate</branch>
  <workingDirectory>[path to repository]</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: I don't have problem pulling from git.  I have current version of CCNet configured according to their documentation and it's pulling from the correct branch .  The problem is that the IfModicationExists build condition is triggering a build when there is a change committed on any branch, not just changes on the  branch that is configured in the source control block.

Comment: In CC.NET dashboard, look at the *View Build Log* link and look at the  `<integrationProperties>` part to verify the `CCNetBuildCondition` value. Is it ForcedBuild or a IfModificationExists ?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand why you use the `<sourcecontrol  type="multi">` instead of `<sourcecontrol type="git">`  http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git

Comment: Because I need to.  I can't share the exact configuration here.